# haproxy configuration for rewriting to /myapp

Tags: redirect, configuration, reverse-proxy, haproxy, forward

Here is my haproxy configuration

```
global
log 127.0.0.1 local2
chroot /var/lib/haproxy
pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
maxconn 16384
user haproxy
group haproxy
daemon
# turn on stats unix socket
stats socket /var/run/haproxy.cmd

defaults
mode http
log global
option httplog
option dontlognull
option httpclose
option forwardfor except 127.0.0.0/8
option redispatch
retries 3
timeout http-request 10s
timeout queue 1m
timeout connect 20s
timeout client 45s
timeout server 45s
timeout check 20s
maxconn 16384

listen stats :9000
mode http
stats enable
stats uri /haproxy
stats realm HAProxy\ Statistics
stats auth haproxy:password
stats admin if TRUE

listen http :80
    #balance leastconn
    #balance roundrobin
    balance source
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor
    server web1 10.0.2.10:8080 check inter 3000 rise 2 fall 3
    server web2 10.0.2.11:8080 check inter 3000 rise 2 fall 3
# acl has_www hdr_beg(host) -i www
# http-request redirect code 301 location myapp
```

---

It is working like this:

I type `http://www.example.com:8000` or `http://www.example.com` so it goes to jboss's 8080 port.
My application is actually accessible through `example.com/suite` but because the port 80 is blocked by ISP, that's why I am using the port 8000 and because of this; my application is accessible through `example.com:8000/mypp`

I want to use haproxy config to forward whoever types example.com:8000 to example.com:8000/myapp

How to achieve it?
I am missing something right?

Answer (score 0):

When you define "Server" in your backend nodes section, you can have URI attached to the IP and port like below to achieve what you are looking for,

```
defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000

frontend localnodes
    bind 0.0.0.0:9876
    mode http
    default_backend nodes

backend nodes
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
    server web01 127.0.0.1:8443/**myApp** check
```